# Getting error when importing CV2 in python tried all solution on Stackoverflow

Tags: python, opencv

I am facing a problem while importing cv2 in python.

> Error - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not
>   be found.

i tried all the solution given in stackoverflow, but still facing the same problem

i am using `python 3.7`
and i used `pip install opencv-python`
and pip install (.whl file)

but didn't worked out for me please help me out with this.

Comment: Show us the output of `pip --version`.

Comment: What OS are you running: Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10, Ubuntu, MacOS?

Comment: @James With DLL load failed there's only one choice - Windows.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski right!  I need coffee.

Comment: By far the easiest way to get OpenCV working on Windows, is to download the [official windows release](https://opencv.org/releases.html), and take the appropriate `cv2.pyd` from a subdirectory of `opencv/build/python`. Place that where Python can find it (e.g. same place as your script), and you're set. (of course, you still may need the right MSVC redistributable installed)

Comment: @james i am using windows 7

Comment: @DanMašek i tried this method too

Comment: What you can try is to inspect the `pyd` (which is really a DLL with a different extension) with some [dependency walker](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to see what's missing.

Comment: @JohnGordon Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\izaz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-package
s (3.4.3)

Answer (score 0):

Installing opencv via pip on Windows is not trivial. In your case the most likely scenario is that you got Python bindings, but not actual OpenCV (pip won't complain) - hence the error.

I'd recommend going with Anaconda as described on [learnopencv](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-and-dlib-on-windows-python-only/).

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQ on the `opencv-python` PIP package (https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

> Q: Import fails on Windows: `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`?
>
> A: If the import fails on Windows, make sure you have Visual C++ redistributable 2015 installed. If you are using older Windows version than Windows 10 and latest system updates are not installed, Universal C Runtime might be also required.
>
> If the above does not help, check if you are using Anaconda. Old Anaconda versions have a bug which causes the error, see this issue for a manual fix.

Comment: is Anaconda is required coz i am using PyCharm IDE

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after comparing the missing dependencies from python.exe and cv2.pyd I noticed that MF.DLL was missing from cv2.pyd but not from python.exe.

I beleive the underlying issue is I installed Windows 10 N  (N for no windows media) thinking I wouldn't need the media player.

I got the missing .dll from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack